# Wordpress MultiSite - Showing Latest Blogs of ALL Sites?

Tags: php, wordpress

In experimenting with Multisite, I see that each site gets it's own WP tables which are numbered.

Is there any efficient way to get combined results among sites? Or are they completely independent in database?

One thing I'd like to do is have a list of latest blogs on front page. Yet I see no apparent way to do this.

Forgive the fact there is no code or "attempts" on this question. Its completely new for me.

Comment: What do you mean by combined results?

Comment: Such as getting all the latest blogs entries in one query, for a special "latest" front page.

Comment: Try this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-create-a-list-of-all-multi-sites-or-blogs-within-one-site

Comment: I'll start with this thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display recent global post in wordpress multisite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713801/how-to-display-recent-global-post-in-wordpress-multisite)