# How to display recent global post in wordpress multisite

Tags: php, wordpress

I run a wordpress multisite on ayp.no and I am trying to figure out a way to present all subsites with logos and recent posts from all blogs, I know there is a wpmudev premium plugin for this, but I was hoping there was some coding i could do myself (well, obviously not myself,  but at least ask here and see)..

Comment: well, i really wish i was good enough with coding to figure it out myself, but alas, thats why i have to ask. :/ Thank you for your answer thou.

Comment: If the answer below worked for you please either comment or mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 4):

First, we need a [function to get all sites](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/114749/12615), with that at hand we iterate thought the array of sites and pull the information with [`wp_get_recent_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) (which is a customized version of [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)).

Use the following as a [Must Use plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins), so the function `b5f_print_recent_posts()` is available throughout the network:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Recent Network Posts
 * Plugin URI: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23713801/1287812
 * Description: Creates a function that lists recent posts from all sites of the network. Call it in another plugins or themes.
 * Author: brasofilo   
 */

/**
 * Iterates throught all sites of the network and grab the recent posts
 */
function b5f_print_recent_posts()
{
    $blogs = b5f_get_blog_list( 0, 'all', true );
    $current_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
    foreach( $blogs as $blog ) 
    {
        switch_to_blog( $blog[ 'blog_id' ] );
        echo '<h3>' . $blog['name'] . ' - ' . $blog['domain'] . ' - ' . $blog['desc'] . '</h3>';
        $posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array(), OBJECT );
        if( $posts )
        {
            foreach( $posts as $post )
            {
                printf(
                    '- <a href="%s">%s</a><br />',
                    get_permalink( $post->ID ),
                    $post->post_title
                );
            }
        }
    }
    switch_to_blog( $current_blog_id );
}

/**
 * Returns an array of arrays containing information about each public blog 
 * hosted on this WPMU install.
 * 
 * Only blogs marked as public and flagged as safe (mature flag off) are returned.
 *
 * @author Frank Bueltge
 * 
 * @param   Integer  The first blog to return in the array.
 * @param   Integer  The number of blogs to return in the array (thus the size of the array).
 *                   Setting this to string 'all' returns all blogs from $start
 * @param   Boolean  Get also Postcount for each blog, default is False for a better performance
 * @param   Integer  Time until expiration in seconds, default 86400s (1day)
 * @return  Array    Returns an array of arrays each representing a blog. 
 *                   Details are represented in the following format:
 *                       blog_id   (integer) ID of blog detailed.
 *                       domain    (string)  Domain used to access this blog.
 *                       path      (string)  Path used to access this blog.
 *                       postcount (integer) The number of posts in this blog.
 *                       name      (string) Blog name.
 *                       desc      (string) Blog description.
 */
function b5f_get_blog_list( $start = 0, $num = 10, $details = FALSE, $expires = 86400 ) {

    // get blog list from cache
    $blogs = get_site_transient( 'multisite_blog_list' );

    // For debugging purpose
    if ( defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) && WP_DEBUG )
        $blogs = FALSE;

    if ( FALSE === $blogs ) {

        global $wpdb;

        // add limit for select
        if ( 'all' === $num )
            $limit = '';
        else
            $limit = "LIMIT $start, $num";

        $blogs = $wpdb->get_results(
            $wpdb->prepare( "
                SELECT blog_id, domain, path 
                FROM $wpdb->blogs
                WHERE site_id = %d 
                AND public = '1' 
                AND archived = '0' 
                AND mature = '0' 
                AND spam = '0' 
                AND deleted = '0' 
                ORDER BY registered ASC
                $limit
            ", $wpdb->siteid ), 
        ARRAY_A );

        // Set the Transient cache
        set_site_transient( 'multisite_blog_list', $blogs, $expires );
    }

    // only if usable, set via var
    if ( TRUE === $details ) {

        $blog_list = get_site_transient( 'multisite_blog_list_details' );

        // For debugging purpose
        if ( defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) && WP_DEBUG )
            $blog_list = FALSE;

        if ( FALSE === $blog_list ) {

            global $wpdb;
            $current_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
            foreach ( (array) $blogs as $details ) {
                $blog_list[ $details['blog_id'] ] = $details;
                $blog_list[ $details['blog_id'] ]['postcount'] = $wpdb->get_var( "
                    SELECT COUNT(ID) 
                    FROM " . $wpdb->get_blog_prefix( $details['blog_id'] ). "posts 
                    WHERE post_status='publish' 
                    AND post_type='page'" 
                );
                switch_to_blog( $details['blog_id'] );
                $blog_list[ $details['blog_id'] ]['name'] = get_blog_details()->blogname;
                $blog_list[ $details['blog_id'] ]['desc'] = get_bloginfo( 'description' );
            }
            switch_to_blog( $current_blog_id );
            // Set the Transient cache
            set_site_transient( 'multisite_blog_list_details', $blog_list, $expires );
        }
        unset( $blogs );
        $blogs = $blog_list;
    }

    if ( FALSE === is_array( $blogs ) )
        return array();

    return $blogs;
}
```

You can add the following network dashboard widget in the previous plugin to test it out:

```
add_action( 'wp_network_dashboard_setup', 'dashboard_setup_so_23713801' );

function dashboard_setup_so_23713801() 
{
    wp_add_dashboard_widget( 'widget_so_23713801', __( 'Test widget' ), 'print_widget_so_23713801' );
}

function print_widget_so_23713801() 
{
    b5f_print_recent_posts();
}
```

Comment: I can't believe you haven't gotten more upvotes for this. You saved my bacon! Thank you!